# QT creator gcc cout in terminal

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

I am just tested simple program on Ubuntu in QT Creator. And problem is that 'cout' and 'cin' does not write / read from terminal. If i turned off terminal than 'cout' is writing text into Application Output but reading from it is not supported. How i can read and write from terminal? And I could use just gcc compiler without QT library.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << x;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to: Tools->Options->Enviroment->General 
and change terminal value to "/usr/bin/xterm -e" without brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make sure to check below option

```
Project->Run settings->check <Run in Terminal>
Add CONFIG += console in .pro
```

Comment: @Tino CONFIG += console added in pro?